# Audio ScriptProcessorNode outputBuffer contains only 0 in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, audio, html5-audio

I'm trying to make an Audio ScriptProcessor that does some stuff with my audio, but I can't debug it in Chrome. On firefox it works fine, but in chrome my sound overpowers (a lot, my soundcard basically says full power all the time, though I've the volume down at 40%). My main problem is that I can't debug it in chrome, because my outputBuffer only contains 0s, even after I've copied the inputBuffer over. But there's still sound for some reason. The important part of my code:

```
function processAudio(evt) {
 var inputBuffer = evt.inputBuffer;
 var outputBuffer = evt.outputBuffer;


 for (var channel = 0; channel < 2; channel++) {
    var inputData = inputBuffer.getChannelData(channel);
    var outputData = outputBuffer.getChannelData(channel);

    for (var i = 0; i < inputBuffer.length; i++) {
      outputData[i] = inputData[i];
      // At this point outputData[i] = 0, but inputData[i] is not 0
      // The audio plays normally, so there obviously is something in the outputBuffer
    }
  }
}
```

When I set a breakpoint at the end of the outer loop, I can see that the inputData is full of numbers, but the outputData only contains 0s. Am I missing something?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, might not help, what do you have when you log these values, without using a break point ?

Comment: @Kaiido Interesting, when I log them the the values show up. Not sure what Chrome is doing there...

Comment: From some personal tests, I think they do run the Audio API on a parallel thread. This would mean that by the time the breaks occurs, the values held in the script-processor may not be here anymore. But I am really surprised that ScriptProcessor behaves the same. And all this is just suppositions,  I never found (nor searched for) any reliable source stating that what I'm saying is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I know what's going on (maybe somebody can verify this...). As @Kaiido points out, the Audio API seems to run on a parallel thread, meaning, the outputBuffer just get's pulled out after some time from the Audio Thread, leaving only 0s. If I do this (not beautiful, but serves my purpose):

```
function processAudio(audioProcessingEvent) {
  var inputBuffer = audioProcessingEvent.inputBuffer;
  var outputBuffer = audioProcessingEvent.outputBuffer;

  var inputData = inputBuffer.getChannelData(channel);
  var outputData = outputBuffer.getChannelData(channel);

  for (var sample = 0; sample < outputBuffer.length; sample++) {
    outputData[sample] = ((Math.random() * 2) - 1) * 0.2;         
  }

  console.log("first = " + outputData[0]);

  // Delay 200ms until the outputBuffer gets pulled
  var date = new Date();
  var curDate = null;
  do { curDate = new Date(); }
  while(curDate-date < 200);

  console.log("first_delay = " + outputData[0]);
}
```

I get this result:

```
first = 0.060469988733530045
first_delay = 0
first = -0.026373833417892456
first_delay = 0
first = -0.037974122911691666
first_delay = 0
```

Guess I'll have to try debugging with firefox or something else.